# Prove that $0.5x^2 -3x ≥ -4.5$ for all real numbers x.

Tags: inequality, formal-proofs

I'm not familiar at all with inequality proofs. How do I approach this problem?

Comment: Try factoring $0.5x^2-3x+4.5$.

Comment: Try calculating the discriminant of $0.5x^2-3x+4.5$.

Answer (score 4):

Let $f(x)=0.5x^2-3x+4.5$

$$f(x)=0.5(x^2-6x+9)=0.5(x-3)^2\ge0$$
for all real $x$.

Thus,
$$0.5x^2-3x\ge-4.5$$

Answer (score 1):

$$0.5x^2-3x\ge -4.5\iff x^2-6x\ge -9\iff x^2-6x+9\ge 0=(x-3)^2\ge 0$$ This last inequality is evident.

Answer (score 1):

Just another way: by AM-GM inequality $0.5x^2+4.5\geqslant 2\sqrt{2.25x^2}=3|x|\geqslant 3x$.